# Inserting a values of one column from a table into another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, custom-function

I am looking for a ways to implement in power query or by using DAX

I do have two tables

**Table_1** is as shown below:

```
Date          Simple    ActualValue    Result
15.07.2023      A         Null       Result from Table_2 considering date 
15.07.2023      B          20           20
15.07.2023      C          30           30
15.07.2023      D          40           40
15.07.2023      E          20           20
15.07.2023      F          12           12
15.07.2023      G         Null      Result from Table_2 considering date 
16.07.2023      A         Null      Result from Table_2 considering date
16.07.2023      B          35        35
16.07.2023      C          42        42
16.07.2023      D          53        55
16.07.2023      E          60        60
16.07.2023      F          17        17
16.07.2023      G         Null      Result from Table_2 considering date
```

**Table_2**:

```
Complex  Field_1  Operator_1   Field2  Operator_2    Field_3    Formula()
A        B     +          C     Null         Null        B+C
G       E      *          D          /       F          E*D/F
```

Formula column in Table_2 is a dynamically merged column from Table_2 and

I am looking for ways to dynamically calculate result for the Formulas of Table_2 by looking up values from Table_1 considering the Dates

Please do provide some suggestions.

Comment: Why does Complex `G` resolve to `(E * D) / F` and not `E * D / F`? What rule determines the precedence?

Comment: my bad this has t be E*D/F,

Let me know if you need any further detaisl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Expression.Evaluate` for this issue.
Also in the code below, I did NOT include the `Formula()` column in my source data, but rather generated the formula in situ showing only the result.

Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor.
Then, if necessary, change the Table Names in the two Source lines to reflect your actual Table names in your workbook.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    Table_1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Simple", type text}, {"ActualValue", type nullable number}}),
    Lookup = Record.FromList(
                Table_1[ActualValue],
                Table_1[Simple]),

//Table_2
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    Table_2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source2), each {_, type nullable text})),

//Calculate Formula
    #"Add Calc Formula" = Table.AddColumn(Table_2, "Formula Result", (rw)=>
        let 
            r = Record.RemoveFields(rw,"Complex"),
            str = Text.Combine(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(r),{"Null",null},Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)," "),
            formula = Expression.Evaluate(str,Lookup)
        in 
            formula, type number)

in
    #"Add Calc Formula"
```

**Table_1**
[image]

**Table_2**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

***Edit to account for different dates for different values
and also results being added to Table_1***

***New Table_1***
[image]

***Revised M Code***

```
let

//Table_2
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    Table_2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source2), each {_, type nullable text})),

//Table_1
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    Table_1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Simple", type text}, {"ActualValue", type nullable number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Table_1, {"Date"}, {
        {"Result From Table_2", (t)=>
            let
                Lookup = Record.FromList(t[ActualValue],t[Simple]),  
                rws = Table.SelectRows(Table_2, each List.ContainsAny(Table_2[Complex], t[Simple])),
            
            //Calculate Formula
                #"Add Calc Formula" = Table.AddColumn(t, "Result From Table_2", (rw)=>
                    if rw[ActualValue] = null then
                    let 

                    //select the correct row from Table_2
                        r = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.SelectRows(Table_2, each [Complex]=rw[Simple]),"Complex"){0},

                    //Create the formula
                        str = Text.Combine(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(r),{"Null",null},Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)," "),
                    
                    //evaluate the formula
                        formulaResult = Expression.Evaluate(str,Lookup)
                        
                    in 
                        formulaResult
                    else rw[ActualValue])
            in 
                #"Add Calc Formula",
                type table[Date=date, Simple=text, ActualValue=nullable number, Result From Table_2=number]}
        }),
    #"Expanded Result From Table_2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Result From Table_2", 
        {"Simple", "ActualValue", "Result From Table_2"})
in
    #"Expanded Result From Table_2"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron,
The calculation of Complex KPI also has to be based on different Dates, the result to be placed in Table_1(by replacing Null). 

 
The solution is working for only one calendar date, if we have multiple dates its throwing me an error 'expression already exists'(i.e simple KPI value already exist).

Comment: @Juli I'm not sure what you mean and you don't seem to show that in your example. Perhaps a solution might be to create separate `Lookups` for the different dates through use of the `Table.Group` function.

Comment: I have edited few changes to my post,  that might give you an understanding  of what I am trying to achieve. 
I am a new bee to Power BI, Would eb great if you could help me

Comment: @Juli I have edited my answer to include a method of using a specific date for the Values, and also for returning the results to `Table_1` as you show. A similar algorithm is used for the calculation, but it is done as an aggregation withing the `Table.Group` function.

Comment: Thank you for your great support. It working as expected. 

A question came to me out of curiosity, would it be possible to do with DAX?

Comment: @Juli I would think it possible to do in DAX, and I have no idea which would be more efficient. I am not a DAX expert.

Answer (score 0):

Import Table1 and Table2 as queries.

Then make a "FormulaContext" query that returns a record of each field value. For example...

```ml
let
  Source = Table1,
  AsRecord = Record.FromList(
    Source[ActualValue],
    Source[Simple]
  )
in
  AsRecord
```

If you're doing what I think you're doing, you'll find that your formula evaluation will have quirks and exceptions, so it's best to create a separate function query that takes a row from Table2 and returns the output of the formula. Let's call it "fValueFromFormula", starting with code of

```ml
(r as record) => Expression.Evaluate(
  r[#"Formula()”],
  FormulaContext
)
```

and then if any steps involved in evaluating your queries get more complicated, defining it as a standalone function will make your code easier to reason through.

For a great understanding of `Expression.Evaluate` I *highly* recommend [Chris Webb's blog post at blog.crossjoin.co.uk](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/02/06/expression-evaluate-in-power-querym/)

Now you've got what you need and it's set up so nicely that the last step is boring!

```ml
Table.AddColumn(
  Table2,
  "Formula Result",
  fValueFromFormula,
  type number
)
```

The above will evaluate your formula into new column "Formula Result"!

Also, it gets more interesting. If you add functions to `FormulaContext` then (and only then) those functions can be used within your formulas! So, if the second argument of the above call to `Expression.Evaluate` was `[#"Number.Ln" = Number.Ln] & FormulaContext` then your formula would have access to do natural logs, and if the second argument was `#shared & FormulaContext` then your formulas could use any and every function available to you within power query because `#shared` is a special variable in power-query that returns everything available in the current context. Within Expression.Evaluate, it's whatever is passed in as the second argument, but directly within your queries it's a record of every function and every query! It's awesome.

You can also look at Chris Webb's blog for great posts on error handling, so when there's an error in a formula, you can try to respond with a descriptive message to help understand what's wrong.